# How to return all inserted bulk data Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I use bulk insertion in Laravel:

```
return User::create($user);
```

Where `$user` is array of rows.

How to return successfully inserted rows as array?

Now it returns only last inserted model.

Full code is:

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->email as $key => $value) {
        $hashed = Hash::make($key);
        $user = [
            "name" => $request->get('name')[$key],
            "email" => $value,
            "password" => $hashed,
        ];
    }

    return User::create($user);
}
```

Could I do the following?

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->email as $key => $value) {
        $hashed = Hash::make($key);
        $user = [
            "name" => $request->get('name')[$key],
            "email" => $value,
            "password" => $hashed,
        ];
    }

    try {
       User::create($user);
       return $user;
     } catch ($e) {
     }
}
```

Comment: I have tried ::insert, in return boolean instead inserted model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work:

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $created = [];
    foreach ($request->email as $key => $value) {
        $hashed = Hash::make($key);
        $user = [
            "name" => $request->get('name')[$key],
            "email" => $value,
            "password" => $hashed,
        ];
        $created[] = User::create($user);
    }
    return $created;
}
```

Or if you want to use bulk insert, you have to select the inserted models after, like this:

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $users = [];
    foreach ($request->email as $key => $value) {
        $hashed = Hash::make($key);
        $users[] = [
            "name" => $request->get('name')[$key],
            "email" => $value,
            "password" => $hashed,
        ];
    }

    if(User::insert($users))
    {
        return User::whereIn('email', array_column($users, 'email'))->get();
    }

    return 'error';
}
```

Comment: That is not bulk, or no matter?

Comment: For bulk you have to use insert, but as you said it returns a boolean not the inserted models. You have to decide if you want bulk insert or returns all created models, My solution is, IMHO, clean and a good compromise.